# Trouble setting JavaScript variable of object using ternary operator

Tags: javascript

Hi Guys I’m having trouble trying to set a variable (val) to be one of 2 possible object attributes. The below code explains what I’m trying to do.

```
function myFnct(elem, imgSrcType) {
  var val = imgSrcType == "bg" ? elem.style.backgroundImage : elem.src;  
  val  = 'image.jpg'  
}
```

I’m using a ternary operator to try and avoid having to write:

```
if (imgSrcType === "bg") {
    elem.style.backgroundImage = "url('image.jpg')";
}
else {
    elem.src = "image.jpg";
}
```

Basically the ‘val’ variable is not getting set correctly as I guess its something to do with elem object. I’m trying to avoid using the if statement as I will need to use it a few times within the function. And I’m trying to keep is as DRY as possible.

Any help getting it to work with the ternary operator method would be awesome!

Comment: You cannot directly do what you're trying to do in JavaScript. Your `if` statement is the proper approach.

Comment: whatever you do to the val, in the second line you set it to a constant value, so basically your `?` operator does nothing, it is overwritten by another value

Answer (score 0):

```
if (imgSrcType === "bg") {
    elem.style.backgroundImage = "url('image.jpg')";
}
else {
    elem.src = "image.jpg";
}
```

ugly but working rewrite:

```
void (
      imgSrcType === 'bg' 
        && (elem.style.backgroundImage = "url('image.jpg')")
        || (elem.src = "image.jpg") 
);
```

Equals:

```
void (
      imgSrcType === 'bg' 
        ? (elem.style.backgroundImage = "url('image.jpg')")
        : (elem.src = "image.jpg") 
);
```

So by adding parentheses **(**`elem.src = "image.jpg"`**)**  you *can* do the assignment. You can also use a comma to return something in a value assignment.

Using this knowledge, you could rewrite `myFnct`:

```
function myFnct(elem, imgSrcType) {
  var val = ( 
              void( imgSrcType == "bg" 
                     ? (elem.style.backgroundImage = "url('image.jpg')") 
                     : (elem.src = "image.jpg") ), //<= ternary done - comma
              'image.jpg' 
            );  
   //now val = 'image.jpg'
}
```

**Note**: this is all about *what is possible*. If you need/want to keep your code readable, using the `if ... else` statement is the better option.

Comment: Excellent. That explains it very well. Regular if statement it is then! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operations can only assign their outcome to a single variable.  They are useful if you are setting that single variable to different values depending on the result of a boolean expression.  Since you are trying to assign the image URL to either the background-image or to the source, you cannot use a simple ternary operation.  The other answers are using pretty complex/quasi-obfuscated code to accomplish what could be done with a simple if/else statement.  Your code - especially for such a simple operation - should be easy to read.  So, I recommend just sticking with the following:

```
function setImage(elem, imgSrcType)
{
    var imgURL = "image.jpg";

    if(imgSrcType == "bg")
    {
        elem.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgURL + "')";
    }
    else
    {
        elem.src = imgURL;
    }
}
```